# How to get backgroundImage url in cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

I was trying to get banner of my Anime-Planet account for my scraper system.
I tried everything i have know with cheerio but i couldn't get the `profileBackground`s `background-image` url.
[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivxus.jpg)

I tried

```
async function Al() {
  const cheerio = require("cheerio");
  const url = "https://www.anime-planet.com/users/kyoyacchi";
  const {data} = await client.axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
      "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36",
    },
  });
  const $ = cheerio.load(data);

  return $(".pull-beta.pull-alpha.pullup.editableBanner")
    .find(".wrapper")
    .find("profileBackground");
}
Al();
```

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oich9.jpg)

This one is only returns avatar path.

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about providing a [mcve] and not depending on external URLs for a question to be understood. Your question doesn't include the HTML structure you are trying to parse.

Comment: I will note that there is no `<profileBackground>` element in HTML so your problem likely has something to do with that.

Comment: @Quentin but there is a div with id called "profileBackground"

Comment: You aren't looking for something with an **id** `profileBackground`, you're looking for something of the **type** `<profileBackground>`.

Comment: @Quentin, i can't get it with `$(".profilleBackground")` or with getting ".wrapper" and finding ".profileBackground" in it.

Comment: Why would `.profilleBackground` work? You said it had the **id** `profileBackground`, not the **class** `profilleBackground`.

Comment: @Quentin Yes it has div id `profileBackground` but i can't get to reach it.

Comment: Well, you haven't written code using the syntax that looks things up by ID. Try looking up how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that it's `$('div[id=profileBackground]')`

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the image path with:

```js
axios.get(url)
  .then(({data: html}) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const path = $("#profileBackground")
      .attr("style")
      .match(/background-image: *url *\((.+?)\)/)[1];
    console.log(path); // => /images/users/backgrounds/3966485.jpg?t=1660418964
  });
```

Use `#some-id` to select by the id attribute. In CSS, a bare word refers to a tag name, so `p` is the selector for `<p></p>`. Ids are supposed to be unique in the document, so you don't usually need to specify parent selectors.

The regex above extracts the contents from the parentheses after `background-image: url`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it only returns "`(`"

Comment: I get the full path on Node 18 and Cheerio 1.0.0-rc.12. Can you provide more details on how I can reproduce your error?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I'm using Node 12 and cheerio ver ^1.0.0-rc.12, i tried your code the way it is, it only said "("  that's what i did

Comment: I'm using the same setup as you and it produces the correct output for me. Maybe you're being served a different site?

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/746414614316843152/1064619649431519243/Screenshot_20230116-215817.jpg I'm sure it's the correct site

Comment: Looks like an unusual way to run code. Can you run it on a normal Node installation? There are a lot of weird characters in the regex and I wouldn't be surprised if something's being lost in translation, either on your input text or the response text.

Comment: I was using Aliucord in that screenshot, now that i've tried in Discord's official app, it really worked as you said. https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/746414614316843152/1064622025844473986/Screenshot_20230116-220626.jpg